# Python Behave optional argument

Tags: python, cucumber, python-behave

I am trying to write a test using Cucumber (Behave). The 'given' statement needs to be able to take an optional parameter, it is for verifying the contents in a string.

An example feature syntax for both scenarios would be:

```
Given Verify text "this is a test string"
When String validation is "success"
Then Store form contents.

Given Verify text "this is a test string" exclude "test,trial,hello"
When String validation is "success"
Then Store form contents.
```

The step I tried to implement was:

```
# Verify text "this is a test string" exclude "test,trial,hello"

@given('Verify text "{text_to_clean}" {?: exclude "{excluded}')
def step_verify_text(context, text_to_clean, excluded):
    context.verified = verify_string(text_to_clean, excluded)
```

How do I do this? I tried using the optional symbol of `?`, but I can't figure it out. What do I need to do to use optional parameters?

I am using a Mac on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** `feature` file name and file name inside `steps` folder should match.

for eg: if `feature` file name is `question_regex.feature` then file name inside `steps` folder should be `question_regex.py`

#### 1. Option - Regex Parser

features/question_regex.feature

```
Feature: regex question

  Scenario: first question regex
    Given Verify text "this is a string"
    Then parameter "excluded" is ""

  Scenario: second question regex
    Given Verify text "this is a test string" exclude "test,trial,hello"
    Then parameter "excluded" is "test,trial,hello"
```

features/steps/question_regex.py

```py
from behave import use_step_matcher, given, when, then
use_step_matcher("re")

@given('Verify text "(?P<text_to_clean>.*?)"((?: exclude )"(?P<excluded>.*?)")?')
def step_verify_text(context, text_to_clean, excluded):
    context.myvar = excluded

@then('parameter "(?P<name>.*?)" is "(?P<result>.*?)"')
def step_verify_text(context, name, result):
    return getattr(context, name, None) == result
```

---

#### 2. Option - CFParse

features/steps/question_cfparse.feature

```
Feature: cfparse question

  Scenario: first question cfparse
    Given Verify text 2 "this is a test string"
    Then normal parameter "excluded" is ""

  Scenario: second question cfparse
    Given Verify text 2 "this is a test string" exclude "test,trial,hello"
    Then normal parameter "excluded" is "test,trial,hello"

  Scenario: second question cfparse
    Given Verify text 3 "this is a test string" exclude "hi,hello,I"
    Then normal parameter "excluded" is "hi,hello,I"
```

features/steps/question_cfparse.py

```py
from behave import given, when, then, use_step_matcher, register_type
import parse
use_step_matcher("cfparse")

@parse.with_pattern(r'(?: exclude )"(.*?)"')
def parse_word_optional(text):
    print(text)
    return text.strip()

@parse.with_pattern(r'(?: exclude )')
def parse_exclude(text):
    return text.strip()

@parse.with_pattern(r'"(.*?)"')
def parse_word_between_quote(text):
    return text.strip()

register_type(my1_=parse_exclude)
register_type(quote_word=parse_word_between_quote)
register_type(my_=parse_word_optional)

@given('Verify text 2 "{text_to_clean}"{ignore1:my1_?}{excluded:quote_word?}')
def step_verify_text(context, text_to_clean, ignore1, excluded):
    context.excluded = excluded

@given('Verify text 3 "{text_to_clean}"{excluded:my_?}')
def step_verify_text(context, text_to_clean, excluded):
    context.excluded = excluded

@then('normal parameter "{name}" is {result:quote_word*}')
def step_verify_text(context, name, result):
    return getattr(context, name, None) == result
```

**Note:** `cfparse` parser is not a good option if you have more than one optional `parameters` which comes one after another

Comment: I copy and pasted your suggestion to run it and learn from it, but I get: You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

@given(u'Verify text "this is a test string"')
def step_impl(context):
    raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP: Given Verify text "this is a test string"')

Comment: The cfparse works, although where exclude is I can type anything:     Given Verify text 2 "this is a test string" secludes "test,trial,hello"

Comment: @GemmaMorriss regex is more flexible and works well cfparse have some issue

Answer (score 1):

Regex for the optional part: `(?: exclude "(?P<excluded>[^"]*?)")?`

Do revert the step matcher back to the default `'parse'` if not using Regex parser for all steps.

```py
use_step_matcher('re')


@given('Verify text "(?P<text_to_clean>[^"]*?)"(?: exclude "(?P<excluded>[^"]*?)")?')
def step_verify_text(context, text_to_clean, excluded):
    context.verified = verify_string(text_to_clean, excluded)


use_step_matcher('parse')
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider/try decorating the step implementation function twice:

```py
@given('Verify text "{text_to_clean}"')
@given('Verify text "{text_to_clean}" exclude "{excluded}"')
def step_verify_text(context, text_to_clean, excluded=None):
    context.verified = verify_string(text_to_clean, excluded)
```

I've had some success with this approach in other similar situations.

Comment: I wish this worked but I don't think it does

Comment: @SabrinaLeggett This works for me using `behave` version 1.2.6.